# What is the difference between 楊 and 柳 which both mean "Willow"

Tags: kanji, homophonic-kanji

I've come across two kanji, which are both read `やなぎ`　and both mean "willow".

From what I've found out so far, `柳` has an On'yomi of `リュウ`　and it seems to mean more "things with the qualities of a willow"; while `楊`　has an On'yomi of `ヨウ`　and means the type of tree. That being said it also seems to be a name element.

Can anyone confirm this or shed some more light on the subject?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`柳` やなぎ リュウ:

> - Used for willows which have their branches hanging down including [`しだれやなぎ`](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%80%E3%83%AC%E3%83%A4%E3%83%8A%E3%82%AE). Can refer more broadly to the tall deciduous trees in the willow family and as a general term for shrubs as well according to Kanjigen.
> - Has a frequency of 1169/2501 and is classified as a general usage Kanji according to Kanjidic.

`楊` かわ やなぎ ヨウ:

> - Used for willows which have their branches going upwards including `かわやなぎ` and [`ねこやなぎ`](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8D%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A4%E3%83%8A%E3%82%AE) according to Kanjigen.
> - Has a frequency of 1815/2501 so is less common and is classified as a `人名用{じんめいよう}` Kanji for use in people's names according to Kanjidic.

Comment: I guess a better translation for 柳 would be "weeping willows" then.

Answer (score 4):

According to dictionary.goo.ne.jp, maybe [柳](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/222323/m1u/%E6%9F%B3/) is the collective name for all willows, and [楊](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/226141/m1u/%E6%A5%8A/) may be used for some specific species (カワヤナギ,ネコヤナギ).

However, the kun reading(やなぎ) of 楊 is usually not used, and 楊 is usually only used in some compound words. So when referring to willow, 柳 would be used.

Note that for tree names formed with the two characters may refer to different kinds of trees. E.g, 白楊【はくよう】 may be [ヤマナラシ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A4%E3%83%9E%E3%83%8A%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B7) ([Populus tremula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populus_tremula)), which is not a kind of willow.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers, I appreciate your answer too!